# Chat - Changing absolute to relative position when element reaches bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a chat where a user has an input field to enter the text. When he enters the text and presses Send (or enter) the text is above the input field. Like this:
[image]

What I want: **I want the input field to be at the bottom of the page**. I achieved this using `position: absolute;`

[image]

**BUT when the chat has a lot of fields, you cannot scroll back and see the chat.**

When I set the position to `position: relative;` , you can scroll back the chat.

[image]

So my question is:

**How can I set the input field to be at the bottom ALWAYS, and when the chat-text reaches the top, the user should be able to scroll back to the top.**

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container custom_chat">
    <div class="box box-warning direct-chat direct-chat-warning">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="direct-chat-messages">
                <div class="direct-chat-msg" ng-repeat="message in listOfMessages track by $index" ng-class="{'right':!message.me}">
                    <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix" style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp " ng-class="{'pull-left':message.me, 'pull-right':!message.me}">{{ message.timeMessage }}</span>
                        <span class="direct-chat-name" ng-class="{'pull-left':!message.me, 'pull-right':message.me}"><strong>{{ message.senderFirstName }}</strong></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="direct-chat-text right">
                        <span style="word-break: break-all;">{{ message.content }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer" style="margin-top:20px">
                <form ng-submit="sendMessage()">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Type message..." autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" ng-model="message.content" ng-enter="sendMessage()">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat">Send</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .custom_chat {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 33%;
}
```

I've tried using a container outside this div and making that container position: relative;
I do not understand how offSet can help me here. Please explain if you use offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach with `position:absolute` is fine. But you need to set `overflow:auto` to your `chat-area`.

Check below code sample.

```js
var formatsApp = angular.module('FormatsApp', []);

formatsApp.controller('LinksController', function LinksController($scope) {
  $scope.listOfMessages = ["asdasd"]
$scope.message = "";
  $scope.sendMessage = function(x) {
    $scope.listOfMessages.push($scope.message)
  }
});
```

```css
.direct-chat-messages,
.box-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 33%;
}

.direct-chat-messages {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="FormatsApp" ng-controller="LinksController">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container custom_chat">
    <div class="box box-warning direct-chat direct-chat-warning">
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="direct-chat-messages">
          <div class="direct-chat-msg" ng-repeat="message in listOfMessages track by $index" ng-class="{'right':!message.me}">
            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix" style="margin-top:20px;">
              <span class="direct-chat-timestamp " ng-class="{'pull-left':message.me, 'pull-right':!message.me}">{{ message }}</span>
              <span class="direct-chat-name" ng-class="{'pull-left':!message.me, 'pull-right':message.me}"><strong></strong></span>
            </div>
            <div class="direct-chat-text right">
              <span style="word-break: break-all;">{{ message.content }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer" style="margin-top:20px">
          <form ng-submit="sendMessage()">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Type message..." autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" ng-model="message" ng-enter="sendMessage(this)">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat">Send</button>
                        </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! I totally forgot about overflow. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to separate your chat area from the input field.

For `ol` element, since you're using angularjs, you can `ng-repeat` to create the `li` elements as chat come in.
Something like this:

```
    <div class="custom_chat">
        <ol id="messages" class="chat-messages"></ol>

        <div class="box-footer">
          <form id="message-form">
            <input name="message" placeholder="Type message..." autofocus>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat">Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then in your CSS do this:

```
.custom_chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.chat-messages {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.box-footer {
  background: #e6eaee;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.box-footer form {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.box-footer form * {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.box-footer input {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.chat-messages {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```